# How insert current datetime on insert in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server

I have table which is filled from external application. I need to fill column datetime with current datetime. This column is not filled by insert query provided by external application. Is there some option? Maybe some trigger?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the `Default Value or Binding` for your date column in SQL Server Mgmt Studio to a function like `GETUTCDATE()`

Answer (score 4):

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable
ADD CONSTRAINT [DT_Default]
DEFAULT (GETDATE()) FOR [MyDatetimeField]
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

You can default your timestamp as follows

```
CREATE TABLE X
(
...
[TimeStamp] DATETIME DEFAULT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
)
```